How do I get the merge request URL without needing to do another "git push"?
When I push code that I've committed (using git push), I get a very nice, helpful message from the gitlab server that includes a link I can immediately use to set up a merge request.  It looks something like this:
remote:
remote: To create a merge request for feature/xxxxx, visit:
remote:   https://gitlab.xxxxx.net/xxxxx/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=feature%2Fxxxxx
remote:

This is a very useful message for me, as I can simply copy this link and paste it directly into a web browser.  Directly visiting this link streamlines the process to get the merge request started, as I get to skip several steps that I would otherwise have to complete.
While I get this message every time I perform a git push (after I've committed new changes, that is), I don't always immediately visit that link.  (For example, I may choose to continue revising my code, or at least review my code.)
But later, when I'm ready to start a merge request, I no longer have access to that helpful server text that contains that link.
Of course, this isn't a problem if I have more code to push, but sometimes I don't have additional code to push.  Is there a way I can see this helpful merge request URL again?
I've tried the following:

git push
git push --force

but they both respond with a simple:  Everything up-to-date
So simply doing a git push doesn't work.  (I would have to commit something new, and then doing a git push would give me the information I want.)
My question, restated:  Is there a way I can see the merge request URL (the one given to me by the gitlab server) without having to both re-commit code and re-push?
Thank you.

Merge Request URLs in GitLab are static, they are not relevant to commits you made.
Merge Request is simply a request to merge one branch into another. By default, merge happens to the default branch (e.g., main).
You can simply use the same URL from previous message.
Alternatively, you can construct URL by yourself.

Take original URL from the log:
https://gitlab.xxxxx.net/xxxxx/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=feature%2Fxxxxx

%5B and %5D can be decoded to [ and ] respectively.

URL can be deconstructed in this way:

https://&lt;GITLAB_URL&gt;/&lt;NAMESPACE&gt;/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request[source_branch]=&lt;BRANCH_NAME&gt;


Answer
Simply provide the branch name instead of <BRANCH_NAME>.

For CI pipeline
If you need to construct such a URL in CI pipeline, you can use built-in GitLab variables:

${CI_PROJECT_URL}/merge_requests/new?merge_request[source_branch]=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}


I understand that Merge Request URLs in GitLab are static, and that I can simply use the same URL from the previous message.  The only problem is, is that I often don't have the previous message lying around, as I generally don't save those messages.  That's why I was wondering if there was a simple way to query gitlab to get that URL, without the need to change, re-commit, and re-push code.

You only need a branch name.

If you are OK to query GitLab, why don't you just open the browser and create a Merrge Request? Or if you use SourceTree as a git client, it can navigate you to that page. Or you can write a simple script that takes current branch name and creates a link.

Also, why don't you just create a Merge Request when you got the link? What is your workflow? How can you make the changes, push them, and then lose the link? Are you unsure that you'll merge changes?

I often end up opening the browser to create a Merge Request.  However, that involves typing/selecting the proper base URL, finding the proper links (among many other links), and selecting the proper feature branch to use (out of a dropdown of many other branches).  It's just very convenient for me to copy-and-paste the link directly into a browser's empty URL bar.  (That gets the annoying, repetitive, and error-prone parts out of the way for me.)

You're asking how can I lose the link?  Simple:  I do the git push on a bash terminal, the same terminal I do lots of other work on.  After a time, the link gets pushed up off the top of the screen, so high up in the text history that eventually it's not easy to scroll through anymore.  I can use a dedicated terminal window, I suppose, but terminal windows have a tendency for me to close and/or get lost in clutter, and besides, I would rather not want to manually switch to a separate terminal simply to do a git push .

I see your point. From my perspective, you need to adapt your workflow a bit. This link from GitLab when you do git push is not standard thing. However, for example Source Tree provides you a standard button "Create Pull Request", it can satisfy your needs. Or you can just create a simple script that you will run that will generate a link in the way I've described in the answer based on current repo and branch. I don't see other options.
